Common Mode Range in comparators
What do we mean by Common Mode Voltage Range in comparators, and how does it help in selection of a comparator for any application?

Common-mode voltage range (CMVR) is the range of common mode signals that an amplifier can process without losing linearity and can provide a reliable comparison output. In other words, it defines the acceptable voltage range that can be applied simultaneously to both the inverting and non-inverting inputs of the comparator without causing malfunctions or incorrect behavior.
If you have a single-supply system, the CMVR often starts from ground, which is essential if your input signal is referenced to ground. Otherwise, if you have dual-supply comparators, the CMVR might allow signals to go below 0V which is useful in applications where the signal swings above and below ground. For applications that require high-precision comparison, you'll want something within the CMVR to avoid unexpected output states or increased offset errors.

For a comparator like LM393, the common-mode input voltage range is defined to be from (Vee) to (Vcc-2V), where Vee is the negative supply and Vcc is the positive supply.
For a 5V single-ended supply, it means that the comparator can properly compare input voltages that are both between 0V and 3V.
It cannot output a proper comparison result if the both input voltages are outside that range e.g. 4.5V and 4.7V.
However for LM393, only one of the voltages need to be within the valid range, the other can be outside the valid range and it can produce a valid result.
(In other contexts the definition of common mode voltage may be a bit different)
The range of what input voltages can be properly compared with a comparator helps you to choose a correct comparator for the voltages you intend to measure.
Different comparators have different internal circuitry to support different CM ranges.
Some support comparing also outside their supplies, one comparator might work a few hundred millivolts below Vee and another might work a few volts above the Vcc.

Comparator classification by major parameters
● Propagation delay
● Current consumption
● Output stage type (open collector/drain or push-pull)
● Input offset voltage, hysteresis
● Output current capability
● Rise and fall time
● Input common-mode voltage range.
   Source:  [st.com][1]

Since comparators are designed for the output to go low "0" when the Vin+ is < Vin-, this threshold is the common-mode. It is not the only major spec, but it is important to ensure your signals stay within the linear Vcm range to avoid logic errors or damage.
Otherwise, this logic could fail or worse the maximum level that may lead to damage is exceeded.  Ideally, the common mode range when compared have 0 input offset voltage and current error so that resistor mismatches do not contribute more input offset to Vio from ΔV=IΔR+ΔIR  .

Some types have a very wide Vcm range even outside the supply levels.

Some types with PFET or PNP inputs are designed to operate at ground level (lowest supply or return)

Some types with NFET or NPN inputs work at the V+ supply rail.

Some CMOS types work with both inputs from Rail to Rail (V+ to V- or return)

Some with JFET high input Z or very low pF don't work near either supply rails due to their biasing requirements.

Some comparators have ultra-low input offset, Vio as this parameter can range from < 1uV to 10's of mV.

Some may use chopper technology to null input offset Vio & Iio.

Some people will use a spare Op Amp (OA) as a comparator (and are often regarded as rookies) But if a free device that satisfies a slow analog comparison with a 10 Hz typical BW at high open loop gains satisfies the I/O constraints, then it may be acceptable.
OA's have an integrator to replace all the phase shift in each stage with a first-order stable close loop at unity gain and thus are relatively slow with open loop gain.


If you cannot choose the level to detect, then you must ensure that input levels are always supported by the Vcm range using single or dual supply.
1: https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00050759-introduction-to-comparators-their-parameters-and-basic-applications-stmicroelectronics.pdf
